# Returning a struct via copy, which encapsulates a pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Let's say I have the following:

```
typedef struct a_struct_s
{
     int* dynamic_pointer;
}
a_struct;

a_struct make_struct( int length )
{
     a_struct s;
     s.dynamic_pointer = calloc( sizeof( int ), length );
     // [check here to see if s.dynamic_pointer was allocated]

     return s;
}
```

Since `make_struct()` will return a copy of the struct `s`, will the pointer encapsulated by it leak memory and not be able to be freed? Also, is there a performance cost with the copy itself vs. allocating `s` dynamically as well?

Answer (score 2):

No. Even though you copy the pointer, it still points to the same place, so you can free it.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it? The pointer is not the allocated memory itself - if you copy the pointer, that doesn't in itself allocate memory. If you later call `free()` on it, it will be correctly freed. I. e., this code does not leak memory:

```
a_struct s = make_struct(10);
free(s.dynamic_pointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as the caller of the function calls `free()` on the structure pointer member it will not leak memory.

Remember the rule:
***Memory leak happens when you call `malloc`,`calloc` and never call `free` on the same address. As long as you do, there is no memory leak.***

Note that it is very important to specify the **ownership semantics** when returning dynamically allocated pointers from a function. In short, your interface should explicitly mention that after the function call the dynamically allocated pointer member is owned by the caller.

> **Since `make_struct()` will return a copy of the `struct s`, will the pointer encapsulated by it leak memory and not be able to be freed?**

Yes a copy of the structure is returned but a **[shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy)**.
Basically, this means that the pointer member of the copy of the structure returned points to the same memory location as the one pointed by structure pointer member of `s`.
Since both pointers point to the same address, as long as caller calls `free` on pointer member of returned structure there is no leak.

> **Is there a performance cost with the copy itself vs. allocating `s` dynamically as well?**

Dynamic allocations are always costly and more prone to errors. Use them to the minimum and don't unless you really need them.

Answer (score 1):

no, its fine as you have it from that point of view however you may want to consider having another approach to allocating because returning a struct by value with a pointer to a memory block may not be so obvious that the caller needs to free a member in it.

one approach would be to make the whole struct allocated as well then have a function the free the struct

```
a_struct* alloc_struct( int length )
{
     a_struct s = calloc( 1, sizeof(a_struct) );
     s->dynamic_pointer = calloc( sizeof( int ), length );
     return s;
}

void free_struct( a_struct *p )
{
    if ( p != NULL )
    { 
      free( p->dynamic_pointer );
      free(p);
    }
}
```